# Connect Domain to Host

Tags: dns, host, forge

I think I have just successfully connected my domain to my web host and have done so by following an article. There seems to be 2 different ways of doing so and I wonder if there is a difference between the two.

method 1
Go to your domain provider. Create an A record that points to your web host's ip address.

method 2
Go to your domain provider and edit the nameservers according to what your web host indicated. Go back to your web host and add a DNS record indicating the domain.

I have followed method 1 and it works. Is it any different from the second method? In addition, when typing out a record at the domain provider, what does @, www,  and * mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A record maps a name to one or more IP addresses, when the IP are known and stable.

@ * are same as known as domain name (e.g. yourdomain.com) some domain registrar using @ instead of entire domain and some uses *. In hosting control panel under DNS records there domainname is mentioned instead of @ OR *

If you work with method 1 and changing A record then you will have to change A record to WWW as well to work your domain with www else your domain with www will ended up with no result. You will also have to change all required records such as CNAME (if you have any subdomain), mail (if it is working through hosting provider).

So best practice is to use namererver so you don't need to change every record under Domain Control Panel.